# How to resolve attribute error related to scipy imread and imresize within Cousera neural network assignment?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I am following Andrew Ng's Neural Network and Deep Learning course on Coursera.

Doing the assignment within Coursera's notebook environment called "Logistic_Regression_with_a_Neural_Network_mindset_v6a."

There is an optional and ungraded section at the very bottom titled:
"7 - Test with your own image".

I am trying to run the following code from my own notebook environment.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import scipy
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage
from lr_utils import load_dataset

%matplotlib inline

## START CODE HERE ## (PUT YOUR IMAGE NAME) 
my_image = "my_pet_cat.jpg"   # change this to the name of your image file 
## END CODE HERE ##

# We preprocess the image to fit your algorithm.
fname = "images/" + my_image
image = np.array(ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False))

image = image/255.
my_image = scipy.misc.imresize(image, size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3)).T
my_predicted_image = predict(d["w"], d["b"], my_image)

plt.imshow(image)
print("y = " + str(np.squeeze(my_predicted_image)) + ", your algorithm predicts a \"" + classes[int(np.squeeze(my_predicted_image)),].decode("utf-8") +  "\" picture.")
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-362e8e86085f> in <module>
      5 # We preprocess the image to fit your algorithm.
      6 fname = "images/" + my_image
----> 7 image = np.array(ndimage.imread(fname, flatten=False))
      8 
      9 

AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'imread'
```

I've read that imread and imresize has been deprecated from scipy. Is there a way to make the code allow the use of a custom image from my local notebook environment without having to downgrade to scipy 1.1.0. For some reason my system won't allow me to uninstall or downgrade to scipy 1.1.0.

Comment: You can `plt.imread()`, instead of `scipy.ndimage.imread`, and for the resizing you can use `PIL.Image.resize` instead of `scipy.misc.imresize`. You can check their documentation for the correct arguments. ([docs imread](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) and [docs resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize))

Comment: I added the following line:
my_image = PIL.image.resize(size=(num_px,num_px)).reshape((1, num_px*num_px*3)).T

I get an error: NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined

Comment: That is correct, you haven't imported `PIL`, but `from PIL import Image`, so you can directly use `Image.resize`.